# Using JAXB in multipart web service

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, multipart

I'm writing Jersey client and server using multipart/mix to send request over. Each multipart bodypart is an Java class. Used JAXB to marshal the object at client side and unmarshal at server side.

1. after marshal, print out is xml file, but after send over to server, why print as com.path.data.io.BBody@2b8dd61d? I used whireshark to check, the xml was send over.

Answer: Because that multipart has unmarshal it to an object.

2. get this error on sever side
   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

   - with linked exception:
     [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]

Answer, no need to unmarshal here

Fixed code is showing below.

Java Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="bBody")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BBody {

    @XmlAttribute
    String a;
    @XmlElement
    String b;

    public BBody() {}

    public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

Client side code

```
public ClientResponse multikey(CommonRequest request)
    throws Exception {
String server = request.getURL();
URI path = URI.create(server).resolve("/" + multikey);

Client client = Client.create();
WebResource rRoot = client.resource(path);
WebResource.Builder builder = rRoot.header("Date", date);

// Construct a MultiPart with each operation as a body part
MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
for (BBody bBody : request.getBBodyList()) {
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(BBody.class);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    ctx.createMarshaller().marshal(bBody, writer);
    String custString = writer.toString();
    _log.info ("custString is {}", custString);
      // here print  custString is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><bBody a="2c741c38-f120"><b>foo</b></bBody>

    multiPart.bodyPart(new BodyPart(custString,  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));

}
ClientResponse result = builder.type(MultiPartMediaTypes.createMixed()).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart)
return  new result;
```

}

server side code

```
 @POST
 @Path("{ignore: .+}")
 @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
 public Response bulk(MultiPart multiPart,
                 @Context HttpServletRequest request,
                 @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws SuspendExecution {

    for (BodyPart bodyPart : multiPart.getBodyParts()) {
        log.info("bodypart entity dump {}", bodyPart.getEntity());
        //no need extra unmashal
        BBody bBody = bodyPart.getEntityAs(BBody.class)           
    }
}
```

Comment: Without looking more into your question, `how can I deal with InputStream type in class need to be marshaled to xml?
` Makes no sense. An InputStream is a stream of bytes. How can you pass a stream across a network? A stream is something that is _in progress_. Based on the question, there's a huge gap in understanding of fundamentals. You need to take many steps back and work to understand the basic before tackling a large problem.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'm truly new to this, do you have any suggestion of how to build foundation? like any book. By searching question, always get one piece here and there, it's hard to learn comprehensively.

Comment: I haven't read any books on this, sorry. I will say that when marshalling/unmarshalling, the goal is passing simple data. That's strings, integers, etc. This data can be encapsulated in a Java class, but that class should just be a simple object with getters/setters. Something like an `InputStream` is a complex object that is more than just getters/setters.

Comment: OK, thanks! The InputStream is actually a request content in my code which should not be type InputStream. Besides that, my other two question is pretty as simple as marshal/unmarshal a class only has string. Do you mind to take a quick look?

Comment: Did you add [multipart](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9319) feature ?

Comment: @ulab yep, I added

Comment: @user7552133 Great! you can add it as answer instead of editing the question.